# How to resolve calendar error in R (Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny

Could you help me with the following question:

Why is my calendar wrong in the second option and not in the first option? Could someone help me solve the problem below?

**First option**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

function.cl<-function(){
  df <- structure(
    list(Update = c("2021-01-21","2021-01-21","2021-01-21","2021-01-21","2021-01-21"),
         date = c("2021-04-01","2021-05-02","2021-06-03","2021-07-04","2021-08-05"),
         D1 = c(3,1,4,5,6), DR01 = c(2,4,5,6,7), DR02 = c(6,3,2,6,1),DR03 = c(5,2,8,9,7),
         DR04 = c(3,5,3,3,7)),class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

}   



ui <- fluidPage(
  
  ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                          br(),
                          
                          tabPanel("",
                                   sidebarLayout(
                                     sidebarPanel(
                                       
                                       uiOutput("date"),
                                       
                                       br(),
                                     ),
                                     
                                     mainPanel(
                                     ))
                          )))


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  data <- reactive(function.cl())
  
  output$date <- renderUI({
    all_dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-15'), by = "day")
    disabled <- as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, as.Date(data()$date)), origin = "1970-01-01")
    
    dateInput(input = "date", 
              label = "Select Date",
              min = min(data()$date),
              max = max(data()$date),
              value = max(data()$date),
              format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
              datesdisabled = disabled)
  })
  

  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Second option**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

function.cl<-function(){
  df <- structure(
    list(Update = c("2021-08-21","2021-08-21","2021-08-21","2021-08-21","2021-08-21"),
         date = c("2021-04-01","2021-05-02","2021-06-03","2021-07-04","2021-08-05"),
         D1 = c(3,1,4,5,6), DR01 = c(2,4,5,6,7), DR02 = c(6,3,2,6,1),DR03 = c(5,2,8,9,7),
         DR04 = c(3,5,3,3,7)),class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
  
  historic<-subset(df,df$date<df$Update) 
  
  average<-mean(historic$D1) 
  standard<-sd(historic$D1)
  evol<-subset(df,df$date<df$Update) 
  median_ocup<-sapply(evol[startsWith(names(evol), "DR")], median)
  
  Plot1<-plot(median_ocup[1:10],xlab="Days",ylab="Number",ylim=c(1, 6))
  abline(h=c(average-standard, average, average+standard), col="red", lwd=5)
  
  return(list(
    "Plot1" = Plot1
  ))
  
}   



ui <- fluidPage(
  
  ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                          br(),
                          
                          tabPanel("",
                                   sidebarLayout(
                                     sidebarPanel(
                                       
                                       uiOutput("date"),
                                       plotOutput("Graph"),
                                       br(),
                                     ),
                                     
                                     mainPanel(
                                     ))
                          )))


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  data <- reactive(function.cl())
  
  output$date <- renderUI({
    all_dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-15'), by = "day")
    disabled <- as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, as.Date(data()$date)), origin = "1970-01-01")
    
    dateInput(input = "date", 
              label = "Select Date",
              min = min(data()$date),
              max = max(data()$date),
              value = max(data()$date),
              format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
              datesdisabled = disabled)
  })
  
  
  output$Graph <- renderPlot({
    function.cl()[[1]]

  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

***ERROR:***

```
Warning in max(data()$date) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Warning: Couldn't coerce the `value` argument to a date string with format yyyy-mm-dd
Warning in min(data()$date) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning: Couldn't coerce the `min` argument to a date string with format yyyy-mm-dd
Warning in max(data()$date) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Warning: Couldn't coerce the `max` argument to a date string with format yyyy-mm-dd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `data()$date` doesn't exist as the function `function.cl()` returns only a `list` with "Plot1".  We need to change the `list` output to return the `Date` converted 'date' column as well

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
function.cl<-function(){
  df <- structure(
    list(Update = c("2021-08-21","2021-08-21","2021-08-21","2021-08-21","2021-08-21"),
         date = c("2021-04-01","2021-05-02","2021-06-03","2021-07-04","2021-08-05"),
         D1 = c(3,1,4,5,6), DR01 = c(2,4,5,6,7), DR02 = c(6,3,2,6,1),DR03 = c(5,2,8,9,7),
         DR04 = c(3,5,3,3,7)),class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
  df[c("Update", "date")] <- lapply(df[c("Update", "date")], as.Date)
  historic<-subset(df,df$date<df$Update) 
  
  average<-mean(historic$D1) 
  standard<-sd(historic$D1)
  evol<-subset(df,df$date<df$Update) 
  median_ocup<-sapply(evol[startsWith(names(evol), "DR")], median)
  
  Plot1<-plot(median_ocup[1:10],xlab="Days",ylab="Number",ylim=c(1, 6))
  abline(h=c(average-standard, average, average+standard), col="red", lwd=5)
  
  return(list(
    "Plot1" = Plot1, date = df$date
  ))
  
}   



ui <- fluidPage(
  
  ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                          br(),
                          
                          tabPanel("",
                                   sidebarLayout(
                                     sidebarPanel(
                                       
                                       uiOutput("date"),
                                       plotOutput("Graph"),
                                       br(),
                                     ),
                                     
                                     mainPanel(
                                     ))
                          )))


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  data <- reactive(function.cl())
  
  output$date <- renderUI({
    all_dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-15'), by = "day")
    disabled <- as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, as.Date(data()$date)), origin = "1970-01-01")
    
    dateInput(input = "date", 
              label = "Select Date",
              min = min(data()$date),
              max = max(data()$date),
              value = max(data()$date),
              format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
              datesdisabled = disabled)
  })
  
  
  output$Graph <- renderPlot({
    function.cl()[["Plot1"]]
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

-testing

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much akrun. It worked, one more thing, do you know how I can put this plot on the right side of the calendar?

Comment: @Jose Can you post as a new question. thanks